# I lost my boomdagger enhanced by "…of doom". If I get it back, is it still enhanced?

Tags: munchkin

I had to discard for 100g due to income tax being played. I discarded/sold my boomdagger which was enhanced by "…of doom".

Now would I get the dagger back with or without "…of doom"?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a rules citation for you, but I've always played - in this game and every similar case I can think of - that cards that enter a pile (like the discard pile) are no longer attached or otherwise related to each other. I think this is standard if for no other reason than it would be annoying to keep track of relationships between cards in a pile. So if you have a way of retrieving your dagger from the discard pile, prior attachments would not come back with it.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you discarded your boomdagger, "…of doom" was independently discarded because it was no longer attached to the boomdagger. Getting your boomdagger back does nothing to change that.

Comment: Spoken like an MtG player :)  Unfortunately I think there's no rule that "independently discards" unattached things in Munchkin - instead attachments have the text "This card goes with the item if it is lost, stolen, or discarded". So my interpretation is ultimately the same as yours, but the question is quite reasonable - after all, "goes with" **does** mean remains attached in the "stolen" case.

Comment: I meant to look at the exact rule wording, but then I got pulled away. Figured I'd look later an adjust, but forgot. As the rule wording is different than expected, I'll delete when I get to a computer.